# FFMPEG merge 3 videos and audio together with 1 command

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge 3 videos and 1 audio track to 1 signle video with ffmpeg.

At the moment i got working command which converts 2 videos and 1 audio together.

One video called overlay is with transparent background and is delayed 13 s as well as audio.

```
ffmpeg \
    -i main.mp4 -i click.mp3 -i overlay.mov\
    -filter_complex " \
        [1:a] adelay=13000|13000 [voice]; \
        [0:a][voice] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest [audio_out],setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1920x1080[top]; \
        [2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+13/TB,scale=1920x1080[bottom]; \
        [top][bottom]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:eof_action=pass" \
    -map 0:v -map "[audio_out]" -y -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

I'm not sure if it is possible but my goal is to add intro a.k.a 3rd video before these videos. So in total it would be 3 videos and 1 audio track.

I tried a lot of varations and nothing has worked. Any suggestions?